# Indie horror movie set at gas station/Diner where people are killed in mysterious ways

Tags: story-identification, horror

I'm looking for an indie horror movie set at gas station/Diner where people are killed in mysterious ways. They're trapped inside an invisible dome. I think there are three criminals, two who drive away from the gas station and smash into the invisible wall.

Answer (score 3):

This is [*No Man's Land: The Rise of Reeker*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1090671/).

Criminals, diner, invisible wall, murder.

Comment: Is that where *The Cabin in the Woods* got the invisible wall idea?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I doubt it. Invisible force fields in fiction have been around since the 1950s

Comment: sure, although in the people-getting-killed-in-one-location horror movie context, I'm struggling to think of earlier invisible-wall-surrounding-the-death-zone examples.

Comment: IIRC, there's also an original *Twilight Zone* episode with this theme.

Comment: Hello Robert, could you please click the checkmark next to this question to confirm it is correct, as indicated by your (now deleted) reply?

Comment: A bizarre downvote. For me or the movie?